# Repetition code encoder circuit

Tags: entanglement, error-correction

The repetition code encodes $\vert \psi \rangle  = \alpha \vert 0 \rangle + \beta \vert 1 \rangle \rightarrow \vert \psi \rangle  = \alpha \vert 000 \rangle + \beta \vert 111 \rangle$ using the following circuit:

[image: Circuit]

where $$t_0: \vert \psi \rangle  = (\alpha \vert 0 \rangle + \beta \vert 1 \rangle) \otimes \vert 0 \rangle \otimes \vert 0 \rangle = \alpha \vert 000 \rangle + \beta \vert 100 \rangle$$
$$t_1: \vert \psi \rangle = \alpha \vert 000 \rangle + \beta \vert 110 \rangle$$ 
$$t_2: \vert \psi \rangle = \alpha \vert 000 \rangle + \beta \vert 111 \rangle$$.

I am wondering what is the operator used from $t_0$ to $t_1$?
I understand that an XOR was applied there to get the desired output but what is the explicit operator (gate-wise or matrix-wise) used?

Furthermore, I tried $U = \mathbb{I} \otimes \mathbb{X} \otimes \mathbb{I}$ and applied it to $\vert \psi \rangle$ which resulted in $$\vert \psi \rangle = \alpha \vert 010 \rangle + \beta \vert 110 \rangle$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operator applied from $t_{0}$ to $t_{1}$ is $CNOT \otimes I$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
U_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
As a CNOT gate produces a entangled quantum state, it is not possible to express it as Kronecker product $I \otimes X$.

Your operator $I \otimes X \otimes I$ means that negation $X$ is applied on $|q_1\rangle$ and identical operator $I$ is applied on $|q_0\rangle$ and $|q_2\rangle$ always. There is no connection established between $|q_0\rangle$ and $|q_1\rangle$.

This operation changes your input qubits to $\alpha|000\rangle + \beta|110\rangle$.

Operation from $t_1$ to $t_2$ is decribed by following matrix:
\begin{equation}
U_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Application of $U_2U_{1}$ leads to state $\alpha|000\rangle + \beta|111\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, $(CNOT \otimes I) \vert \psi \rangle = \vert \psi \rangle$, it doesn't change the state to $\vert \psi \rangle = \alpha \vert 000 \rangle + \beta \vert 110 \rangle$

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D1%260%260%260%260%260%260%260%5C%5C%200%261%260%260%260%260%260%260%5C%5C%200%260%260%261%260%260%260%260%5C%5C%200%260%261%260%260%260%260%260%5C%5C%200%260%260%260%261%260%260%260%5C%5C%200%260%260%260%260%261%260%260%5C%5C%200%260%260%260%260%260%260%261%5C%5C%200%260%260%260%260%260%261%260%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7Da%5C%5C%200%5C%5C%200%5C%5C%200%5C%5C%20b%5C%5C%200%5C%5C%200%5C%5C%200%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D

Comment: The gate you’ve written out is $I\otimes$cnot not cnot$\otimes I$

Comment: @M.AlJumaily Al: Apologize for my mistake. Now, it should be all right, I checked my calculation in Octave.

Comment: @DaftWullie: Thanks for checking. I recalculated Kronecker product and expanded answer. Now, it should be all right.

Comment: Now, it is all clear! Thank you so much!